# Truncate string with html tag in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, string, truncate

I want to truncate in Laravel text from database with HTML Tag, for example:

```
<p>Hi. I want to say about my story. </p>
```

I found a method:

```
{{ Str::limit($text, 20) }}
```

But I've problem, because when I truncate this text with length 20, I will have this result:

```
<p>Hi. I want to say
```

I want to get text with closed tags in HTML. I know that such a method is available in different framework as soon as CakePHP. What about Laravel?

Comment: Perhaps [`DOMElement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) would be of use here? Will it always be, simply, a `<p>` tagname? Will it be nested?

Comment: It is only example. Of course can be other cases like <p><div>Text</div</p>

Comment: you can define a function directly taken from CakePHP repo https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/4.x/src/Utility/Text.php#L600=

Answer (score 0):

It's always preferable to parse HTML properly, but if your text is always contained in a single element, it should be safe to treat it as a simple string:

```php
$html = "<div class='container'><p><span class='cj4'>Here’s the long text to be truncated</span></p></div>";
$text = strip_tags($html);
$short_text = Str::limit($text, 20);
$html = str_replace($text, $short_text, $html);
```

This results in:

```
<div class='container'><p><span class='cj4'>Here’s the long text...</span></p></div>
```